# Deserializing a JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, unmarshalling

I have a Java web service response as an object which has a map with integer as key and custom object as value. The custom object in turn consists of a list of another custom object. When I try to deserialize the response, everything is deserialized except the list of custom object. The list is empty.

My code:

```
String dataFromServer ="";
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<OuterCustomResponse>() {}.getType();


OuterCustomResponse respo = gson.fromJson(data, Books.class);
```

`OuterCustomResponse` has the following structure:

```
OuterCustomResponse {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private Map<Integer,CutomObj1> obj;
}

CtomObj1 {
    List<CustomObj2> customObj2;
}
```

The problem is the response contains age, name and the map object, but inside the map object, the list is empty. I tried writing a deserializer for the `CustomObj2` by implementing JSON deserializer, but no use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the `CustomObj1`class implements `Serializable`?  Perhaps, if it does not, it is not possible to serialize it and you get that wrong output.

Comment: i tried implmnting srializablr in customobj1 with no luck.  but customobj1 has other string and intgr attributes whichar obtaind proprly.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is only with `CustomObj2`? What do you have inside? Is it also `Serializable`?

Comment: it is a custom class, i tried implmnig serializabl , but no luck . That clas has primitive data typ variabls

Comment: share the json text please

Comment: Also what does this mean: OuterCustomResponse respo = gson.fromJson(data, Books.class);  you are using Books class as an input to fromJson method but passing it to OuterCustomResponse.

Comment: sorry , it is a typo- it should be :OuterCustomResponse respo = gson.fromJson(data, listType);

Comment: {
    "name": "pass",
    "id": "1",
    "map1": {
        "1": {
            "map1Name": "map1",
            "map2": {
                "2": {
                    "age": 22,
                    "runs": [
                        {
                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: the runs is empty- i hav changed the names due to confidentiality purpos.

Comment: @parameswar is this the original json text? If not, share the original one.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better with some example JSON. (You've got a typo there I guess as well `CtomObj1 {...`)

Maybe `customObj2` isn't an object rather than some primitive type(? unlikely ok) or your list is an associated array (=object) and thus you've got a complex object instead of a list/array?

If it's an associated array (~ object) and just looks like a list:

```
OuterCustomResponse { 
  age:3, 
  name:"foo", 
  map:{ 
    1:{ 
      listitem1a:{...}, 
      listitem2a:{...}}, 
    2:{}, 
    ... 
}}
```

you may have to choose from these 3 options to deserialize generically: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

If it's a list indeed ((indexed) array):

```
OuterCustomResponse { 
  age:3, 
  name:"foo", 
  map:{ 
    1:[ 
      { listitem1propertyA: "bar" }, 
      { listitem2propertyB: "baz" }
    ], 
    2:[], 
    ... 
}}
```

the list items can be of the same or different type.

If they are the same type, your approach should work, if `listitem1propertyA` is mapped correctly to some `CustomObj2.listitem1propertyA` field.

If they are not the same type (or there may be only one exceptional object mismatching - I don't know if that would cause an empty list) again you've got to choose from the above options.